# Android app crashing (shared preferences)

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-alertdialog

I am building an android game that uses saves. That means that a user can open up to 5 unique saves on the game. to create a new save, im using SharedPreferences to let the user enter a save name and store it in my SharedPreferences folder, and then redirect the user to the main game Activity with an Intent Extra that tells the game activity what save to open.

In the design it all sounds ok, but for some reason my application just keeps Force closing.
I dont have any code errors inside eclipse, and even LogCat shows no error. I dont know what
is going on...

Here is my code:

```
package ent.com;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Saves extends ListActivity{

String saves[] = { "Empty save", "Empty save", "Empty save", "Empty save", "Empty save"};
public static String filename = "SharedData";
SharedPreferences someData;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    someData = getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);
    String save1 = someData.getString("0", "Empty save");
    String save2 = someData.getString("1", "Empty save");
    String save3 = someData.getString("2", "Empty save");
    String save4 = someData.getString("3", "Empty save");
    String save5 = someData.getString("4", "Empty save");

    saves[0] = save1;
    saves[1] = save2;
    saves[2] = save3;
    saves[3] = save4;
    saves[4] = save5;

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Saves.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, saves));

}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v,int position, long id) {
    final String clicked = saves[position];
    final String pos = getString(position);
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    if(clicked=="Empty save"){

        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alert.setTitle("Input name");
        alert.setMessage("Give your team a name:");
        // Set an EditText view to get user input 
        final EditText input = new EditText(this);
        alert.setView(input);

        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
          String value = input.getText().toString();
          SharedPreferences.Editor editor = someData.edit();
          editor.putString(pos, value);
          editor.commit();

          try{
          Class Joe = Class.forName("ent.com.TestActivity");
          Intent Joey = new Intent(Saves.this, Joe);
          Joey.putExtra("save", clicked);
          startActivity(Joey);
          }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
              e.printStackTrace();
          }

          }
        });

        alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            Intent back = new Intent("ent.com.MENU");
            startActivity(back);
          }
        });

        alert.show();
    }else{
    try{
    Class ourClass = Class.forName("ent.com.TestActivity");
    Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Saves.this, ourClass);
    ourIntent.putExtra("save", clicked);
    startActivity(ourIntent);
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}

}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: when the application closing? when you are tring to select a saved state from list?

Comment: post app log when app is closing

Comment: then i'm 100% sure you have any issue with starting activity on button clcick

Comment: can you post the logcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far all I see that is a big problem is this :

```
if (clicked=="Empty save")
```

`==` is for numbers and reference comparison.  you're looking for:

```
if (clicked.equals("Empty save"))
```

which will actually compare the strings in question

Comment: Fixed that, though it is still not working.. The second i click an object in the list it shows me the Force Stop message. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: @arielschon12 well... there isn't any reason to call super.onItemClick() I don't know if that will throw an exception or not but you probably shouldn't do it...

Comment: I think the main thing thats causing this is the onClick dialog function. before i filled it with some commands it all worked and clicking one of the menu items will display the dialog. it will just do nothing. I probably should also mention i did nothing with SharedPreferences before, i just used the commands from the internet. do i need to set it up somehow?

Comment: @arielschon12 your shared pref stuff actually looks fine.  Is there a reason you're using class.forName? most situations would call for `TestActivity.class` instead